# Linking inside a webpage without the hashtag

Tags: javascript, css, html

My question is the next. Pretty sure a simple one, but I started programming alone, like two weeks ago, so I have much to learn. I would like to make a menu, with three options.
menu1
menu2
menu3

My question is how to make a link without the hashtag?

SO. When somebody opens up the About, instead of getting the URL www.example.com#menu3, i want them to see www.example.com/menu3.

With this I could achive that I could link any of the submenus on other sites.

I do not want to make another html file for every part of the site, it would be enough just to open a div. (Afterwards I would like to animate it in, but I will try this alone, for now the help I need is to get rid of the # to make a nice structure to the html. Eventually i would put links inside the submenus too, so the result would be like www.example.com/about/submenu)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to make a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)? If not.. what's wrong with pointing to different HTML files?

Comment: What's wrong with using `#`s? Many big frameworks use it for routing.

Comment: I have no problem with it, maybe I just something too easy. :/ If I link to another html file is it possible not to load it in again but display it in a div so the main site does not reload? Eventually fade it in?

Comment: @BalázsOrbán Not without some `ajax` magic.

Comment: can you tell me how? :)

Comment: @BalázsOrbán post a new question if you want to know that in AJAX, although you should attempt it first. Have a look at many of the tutorials, which you can find from the wiki at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info

Comment: I discovered it on some sites source codes, that they wrote:

<a href="/about"> instead of <a href="#about">, and the url than changed to www.example.com/about instead of www.example.com#about . This is what I would like to achive.

Answer (score 0):

A hashtag is used as an anchor for an element your HTML this type of link just moves the screen view to that element rather than linking to a page. If you want to remove the # the only way is to link to another HTML file or website. Using

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Text to be clicked</a>`

this would take you to Google.com.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fount it. It wasn't html or css or js.

I added this to the .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Which results in that www.example.com/about 
will open the www.example.com/about.html

now I just have to figure out, how to animate it in and open it inside a div